# Dask using a high amount of system CPU

Tags: python, dask

I am running a Python process on Dask on my Mac using dask_dataframe.map_partitions. The system CPU is over 70% and the overall run time is slower than expected. Is there any particular for this?

```
Processes: 516 total, 4 running, 4 stuck, 508 sleeping, 4051 threads                                                                            17:01:05
Load Avg: 8.96, 8.63, 8.87  CPU usage: 24.29% user, 71.74% sys, 3.96% idle   SharedLibs: 183M resident, 49M data, 30M linkedit.
MemRegions: 280712 total, 7256M resident, 122M private, 2408M shared. PhysMem: 15G used (3646M wired), 1216M unused.
VM: 3934G vsize, 1298M framework vsize, 337943173(128) swapins, 424866150(0) swapouts. Networks: packets: 54072553/576G in, 52411813/575G out.
Disks: 13274682/1405G read, 10823134/1690G written.
PID    COMMAND      %CPU      TIME     #TH    #WQ   #PORT MEM    PURG   CMPRS  PGRP  PPID  STATE    BOOSTS           %CPU_ME %CPU_OTHRS UID  FAULTS
13116  python3.7    955.1     02:01.53 90/17  1     124   721M-  0B     0B     5984  5984  running  *0[1]            0.00000 0.00000    504  1624296+
```

I can't see any other processes using a lot of CPU except for the python process

If I run the same code not on Dask I don't see the high sys CPU usage so I'm wondering what the system could be doing when running Dask.

Comment: You can test in a other operating system?

Comment: I have tried in linux and don't see the high sys CPU there

Comment: You should give more information about what you are doing and what configuration dask is running in. System CPU usage could come from thread-switching or inter-process communication, for example, not to mention swapping if memory is high.

Comment: I am running the example in this blog post:
https://medium.com/mindorks/speeding-up-text-pre-processing-using-dask-45cc3ede1366

Answer (score 0):

python can take a lot of memory if it is defining variables over and over again. it can also take a lot of time if there are nested loops in your program. maybe this is the problem?

Comment: Wouldn't this appear as user cpu instead of system cpu? I'm questioning these values to be clear: CPU usage: 24.29% user, 71.74% sys.

Comment: I believe not. I think that running code uses up CPU from the system, not the user. Compiling programs is a system thing, and running them is not user based.